# TypeORM: count relation without query builder

Tags: orm, typeorm, nestjs-typeorm

I have 2 `entity`: `Category` and `Product`:

`Category` have `OneToMany` with `Product`.

I want each `category`, it have `total_product` or some thing mean all products of category.

In fact, it have some way using `queryBuilder`.

But I want some way **without** `queryBuilder`, which can work in methods of ORM like `find()`, `findBy()`...